# C# WinForm Проблема с DataBindings

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем доброго.
Есть форма на которой 2а textbox с привязкой(Binding) к DataGridViewRow
Cуть такая. Я Вызываю подчиненное окно. нужно изменить 2а значения. Нажать сохранить.
Они должны сохраниться.
Если написать так то все работает. Ставим  DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged

```
  public DataGridViewRow editrow;

            textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", editrow.DataBoundItem, "Mytable1Id", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
            textBox2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", editrow.DataBoundItem, "Mytable1Name", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

Но мне нужно сохранить в том случае если нажата на кнопку SAVE.
на Cancel сохранение быть не должно

Поэтому пишем так. Ставим DataSourceUpdateMode.Never и пишем обработчик save

```
public DataGridViewRow editrow;
            textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", editrow.DataBoundItem, "Mytable1Id", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never));
            textBox2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", editrow.DataBoundItem, "Mytable1Name", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never));

        // Обработка нажатия на кнопку Save
        private void btSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           MessageBox.Show($"{textBox1.Text} // {textBox2.Text}");  // тут показывает что все значение изменены как нужно.
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
                foreach (Binding b in c.DataBindings)
                    b.WriteValue();
        }
```

Проблема в том что сохраняется только 2е поле?
Почему не биндится поле textbox1? вернее оно биндится но не прописывает в поле editrow.
Что я не так сделал?

Если оставить только один textbox1 то он работает. Если добавить 5 полей то сохранятся будет только последнее.

Ошибка именно в обработке SAVE, потому как если поставить вывод значений то в textbox(ах) значение как и должны быть (Отредактированы).

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решился так

```
        public DataGridViewRow editrow;
        BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource(); 

            bindingSource.DataSource = editrow.DataBoundItem;
            textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bindingSource, "Mytable1Id", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never));
            textBox2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bindingSource, "Mytable1Name", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never));


     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
                foreach (Binding b in c.DataBindings)
                    b.WriteValue();
        }
```